# Button Listener with Fragments

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have number of buttons which ought to pass a different string value to single activity. When I try to include button listener in my main activity I got NullPointer exception and this is killing me as I tried every post from stackoverflow and it should work! I cannot figure out what my problem is. Here is some code:

Button Definition in fragment_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity=""
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="#f000"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    style="@style/lineralLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1s"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/f0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2s"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/f2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/f8"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/f40"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/dont_know"
     android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1s);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2s);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String toParse = new String();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1s:
        toParse = "0";
        break;
    case R.id.button2s:
        toParse = "90";
        break;

    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DuzaKartaActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(TEXT_KEY, toParse);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Code from Fragment Class:

```
public class StandardFragment extends Fragment {

public StandardFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

And the logcat output:

```
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): Process: com.ericpol.scrumpoker, PID: 3265
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ericpol.scrumpoker/com.ericpol.scrumpoker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at com.ericpol.scrumpoker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-12 11:14:28.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: Post your logcat then

Comment: the button 2 is not declared

Comment: `button1s` button is define in `fragment_layout` layout but you are passing `activity_main` layout in `setContentView` method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: changing this did not make any difference - catlog shows the same output

Comment: First of all fragment_layout.xml you've shown us isn't complete. Apart from that it shouldn't be throwing this error. Try to clean n rebuild your project.

Comment: I have inserted more code for fragment_layout. Clean and rebuild didn't help

Comment: Post your whole layout and be done with it. We can't see button2s there and aren't sure if it's even there..

Comment: I have included also fragment class

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't make any difference

Comment: @Lenny impossible. You aren't showing us all of your code.

Comment: @user3249477: I know - it should work. Which part of the code could be important here as there is lot of code inside this activity but the app is loading when i delete button1.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

Your `Button` is defined inside the `fragment_layout` and you are trying to inflate the activity and then `find the view`. This wont work. You either have to `inflate` `fragment_layout` and the call `findViewById`

**or**

Create a class that extends `Fragment` and override the `onCreateView` method and use`FragmentManager` to add the fragment to the activity.
 In the overriden `onCreateView` method you can set the listener

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what the problem was so I have set onClick method within fragemt_layout xml and removed onClick listener from MainActivity.